# Estimate the smallest eigenvalue of T

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

The problem:

> Let $(T\phi)(x)=-\phi ''(x) + x\phi(x)$ be a linear operator acting on the space of functions $$V:=\left\{ {\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}}; \phi(0)=\phi(1)=0\right\}.$$ Estimate the smallest eigenvalue of T.

Okay so this question was totally left field. Reading in my book, I found no true way of making this as general as I assume it needs to be and it does not do a good job of explaining Sturm-Liouville Theory (this equation is in regular Sturm-Liouville form). Here's what I've attempted:

> Obeserve that our equation can re-written as $$-(\phi ')' + x\phi$$ where it is now clear that we're dealing with a regular Sturm-Liouville equation ($[s(x)\phi']' +q(x)\phi +\lambda^2 p(x)\phi)$. Let's find a lower bound for overall equation by multiplying through $\phi$ into our original equation and then integrating on our interval: 
>   $$\int_{0}^1 [-\phi''\phi+x\phi^2]dx$$
>   Performing integration by parts we end up obtaining 
>   $$\int_{0}^1 [(\phi')^2+x\phi^2]dx$$
>   Notice that on our interval, our integral will never be negative 
>   $$\implies \int_{0}^1 [(\phi')^2+x\phi^2]dx \geq 0$$
>   so $0$ is a lower bound.
>
> Now recall that *Rayleigh's method* is estimating the first eigenvalue, where we end up with the *Rayleigh quotient* $$\lambda _1^2 \leq \frac{N(y)}{D(y)}$$
>   where in the most general case we have $$N(y)=\int_{lower}^{upper} [(s(x)\phi')^2+q(x)\phi^2]dx$$ $$D(y)=\int_{lower}^{upper} [p(x) \phi^2]dx$$.

So where do I proceed from here? I feel like if I just consider a function $y(x)$ that satisfies our boundary value conditions, there's always a chance we can find another function that has smaller eigenvalue. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes I'm positive lol. I must've read this problem over 100 times now. Need to find a general way to do this I believe. I don't think that we have to find an exact equation, but just some kind of strange general formulae using Sturm-Liouville theory (that was not really provided in my book).

Comment: Where did you get the k*y[x] from btw?

Comment: The zero-function is one solution, but there are other solutions known as Airy functions.

Comment: _there's always a chance we can find another function that has smaller eigenvalue_ That's why that method will give you just an upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenfunctions to the operator $T$ are those satisfying

$$-\phi'' + x\phi = \lambda\phi$$

where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

Switching variables to $y = x-\lambda$ the equation becomes

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dy^2} = \phi y$$

This is the equation for the Airy functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). The general solution to the eigenvalue problem can be written

$$\phi(x) = a Ai(x-\lambda) + b Bi(x-\lambda) $$

Now imposing the boundary condition at $x=0$

$$0 = a Ai(-\lambda) + b Bi(-\lambda) $$

Certainly $a=b=0$ is a solution (for any $\lambda$), I will neglect this. This leads to

$$\phi(x) = C\left[Ai(x-\lambda)Bi(-\lambda) - Ai(-\lambda) Bi(x-\lambda)\right]$$

for some constant $C\not = 0$. Now for the second boundary condition to be satisfied we need

$$Ai(1-\lambda)Bi(-\lambda) = Ai(-\lambda)Bi(1-\lambda)$$

It can be shown, using the properties of the Airy functions, that this equation has a smallest solution which numerically turns out to be $\lambda \approx 10.3$.